# HTML and Clickable table cell

Tags: php, html, popupwindow

I need to make a cell of an HTML table clickable. When this event occurs, a pop-up or windows is shown with some information.
Here my current HTML code:

```
<table class="table1">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">AAAA</th>
        <th scope="col">BBBB</th>
            ....

    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php 
    $mystring = "";
            ...
            echo '<td scope="row" style="width: 300px">'.$mystrin.'</td>';
    echo '<td style="background-color:#FFFFFF"></td>';
            ...
?>       
</tbody>
</table>
```

Now, "$mystring" is displayed inside the cell. I would like to have a cell colored (e.g., background-color:#388643") and if I click on it, a pop-up is displayed with the string "$mystring".

To create a pop-up I use:

```
     echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert($mystring);</script>";
```

but I'm not able to link this with the event "click on this cell"

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener

Comment: Did you tried to make a javascript event like onclick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using pure javascript, without js framework

```
<tbody>
<?php 
    $mystring = ""; //remember to remore the ' symbol
        ...
        echo '<td scope="row" style="width: 300px" onclick="alert(\'' .$mystrin. '\');">&nbsp;</td>';
        echo '<td style="background-color:#FFFFFF"></td>';
        ...
?>       
</tbody>
```

Comment: This works well! Just one thing. In the cell is displayed the message. I need that the string is shown only in the pop-up

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
<tbody>
      <td scope="row" style="width: 300px" id="click"><?php echo $mystring; ?></td>
    <td style="background-color:#FFFFFF"></td>     
</tbody>
```

in script

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$("#click").click(function(){
var value=$("#click").val();
alert(value);

});
</script>
```

Comment: You might want to mention that this soultion needs jQuery to work http://jquery.com/